# Loop through all checkboxs in a div with certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to loop through certain checkboxes with a specific class that are inside a div.
I know how i can achieve this by adding ID's to each and everyone of them but that's not what i want to go for. Below is my code

JS

```
<script>
function calculate()
{
    $('#payments').find('.checkBoxP').each(function() {
        if ( $('.checkBoxP').prop('checked') )
        {
            alert('its on');
        }
        if ( !$('.checkBoxP').prop('checked') )
        {
            alert('nope');
        }
    });
}

calculate();
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="row-fluid" id="payments">
   <div class="span4">Sale No # 112<div class="widget-header">
                    <span>Pizza</span>
                        <span class="shopp-price" style="margin-right:5px;"> $<em>10.90</em>
                        </span>
                        <span class="widget-toolbar">
                            <label>
                                <input onchange="calculate();" type="checkbox" class="checkBoxP"></input>
                                <span class="lbl"></span>
                            </label>
                        </span>
                    </div>Sale No # 110<div class="widget-header">
                    <span>Coca Cola</span>
                        <span class="shopp-price" style="margin-right:5px;"> $<em>17.20</em>
                        </span>
                        <span class="widget-toolbar">
                            <label>
                                <input onchange="calculate();" type="checkbox" class="checkBoxP"></input>
                                <span class="lbl"></span>
                            </label>
                        </span>
                    </div>
```

Note that below there are couple more `inputs` which i don't want to include in the search that's why i have inserted the class.

Comment: Use `$(this).prop('checked')` instead `$('.checkBoxP').prop('checked')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check whether the currently iterated checkbox is checked, instead you condition will always check whether the first checkbox is checked or not

```
function calculate() {
    $('#payments').find('.checkBoxP').each(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            alert('its on');
        } else {
            alert('nope');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the most succinct way to do it!

```
function calculate() {
    $("#payments .checkBoxP").each(function() {
        alert($(this).is(":checked") ? "it's on" : "nope");
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4vAPU/

This can also be achieved with pure JavaScript, though in this instance you need to be sure that you implement the correct [polyfills](https://github.com/inexorabletash/polyfill) for querySelectorAll and forEach:

```
function calculate() {
    document.querySelectorAll("#payments .checkBoxP").forEach(function (val, index, arr) {
        alert(arr[index].checked ? "it's on" : "nope");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check current element is checked or not using  `$(this).is(':checked')`

```
function calculate() {
    $('#payments').find('.checkBoxP').each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert('its on');
        } else {
            alert('nope');
        }
    });
}
```

[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mVSPR/60/)

Answer (score 2):

You Can Try this Also

```
function calculate()
{
    $('#payments input.checkBoxP').each(function() {
        if ( $(this).is(':checked') )
        {
            alert('its on');
        }
        else{
            alert('nope');
        }
    });
}

calculate();
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXmQa/)**

Answer (score 0):

Heres a pure JS version

```
function calculate() {
    var checks = document.getElementsByClassName('checkBoxP');
    var checked_elms = [];
    checks.forEach(function(val, index, ar) {
        if(ar[index].checked) {
            checked_elms.push(ar[index]);
        }
    });
    console.log(checked_elms);
}
```